# Count the words and spaces in Microsoft Word

Tags: ms-word

I want to count the words and spaces from a Word document and insert then in a header (or footer) as numbers. I know I can *see* these statistics (from Tools menu), but how can I insert them in a header?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can help you:

[Word Count in Word](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081006211451AA4TR4p)

In Word 2007:

1. Click the Insert tab on the Ribbon.
2. In the Text group, click the QuickParts icon.
3. Click the Fields menu item.
4. Scroll down to and click on NumWords.
5. Click OK.

Comment: @Matchu, you are right, I copied the wrong link. I had multiple tabs and selected the wrong one. This one should help.

Answer (score 2):

1. Insert
2. Header
3. Edit header

then go to **insert menu**

- click on quick Part
- then click on field
- select Numwords for insert word
- click on ok.

Answer (score 0):

This may be outdated, but I found [the following](http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.office.setup&tid=98048190-8938-4205-95cf-013d7f9020b0&p=1):

> Click where you want the word count to
>   appear. Click on Insert |  QuickParts
>   | Field | Field names: NumWords | OK.
>   The field will not  automatically
>   update as you add words to the
>   document, but will be  updated when
>   you open the document or when you
>   click on Print Preview or  when you
>   select the field and press F9.

Something that will update as you type is impossible, but this should be a close second.

Also, belongs on SuperUser.